# Linker Address Map (.map) File in vs2008

Tags: c, dictionary, visual-studio-2008, linker

I am trying to understand LINKER ADRESS MAP(.map) File for storage of global variables & structure variables  in vs2008. I got that, types of all variables is data(type).But object section of variables is differents as .bss or .data.so what is different between .bss &.data

thanx

Comment: DATA is initialized data, BSS is uninitialized data. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

Comment: @VladLazarenko:thanx a lot

Comment: @VladLazarenko:Object section of structure variable should be (.bss) or may be both(.bss) &(.data).